# Windows Forms Button Click Status Text

Tags: windows, label

My windows form application has a button that does 3 things:

1 - Show a message in a label.text: connecting.

2 - Connects to the database.

3 - Change the text of the label to connected.

The problem is that the first message, connecting, is not even shown... goes directly to connected because the compiler do all the background processing and this blocks the first message to be shown. Is stays like frozen until connects to database.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is most likely because your form is not redrawn\updated before your database connection takes place, so the label update won't be seen.  Which language are you using?  If .Net based, try using `Application.DoEvents();` before executing your database connection code.

Comment: @MartinParkin I was already typing Application.DoEvents(); and then your comment popped out like a second before I could press post your answer :) Voted your comment up instead :)

Comment: You got it Martin! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ElvisGabriel I'll add a proper answer for you if you'd like to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because your form is not redrawn\updated before your database connection takes place, meaning that the label update won't be seen.

Before you begin to connect the database, use `Application.DoEvents();` which will cause the form to be updated, and the correct label to be shown.